# NetBeans remote synchronization : failed to save file

Tags: ftp, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans in a project, making use of remote sync to save both locally and to a FTP server. This feature works in other projects, but this time is failing when trying to save the file to the remote server.

The IDE log tells me that had occurred a unknown error, as well as this :

```
Upload failed: org.netbeans.modules.php.project.connections.TransferInfo [transfered: [], failed: {index.php=Cannot upload file index.php (unknown reason).}, partially failed: {}, ignored: {}, runtime: 61136 ms]
    Cannot logout from server
```

The version of the IDE is 6.8.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those still having issues with this (passive mode doesn't work, version 6.9 doesn't work, etc.) you may be running into issues with IPv6 sockets being filtered by Windows Firewall incorrectly. (JDK7 and above use IPv6 sockets when IPv6 is enabled.)

See this bug for more information and workarounds:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696

For the "Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" workaround, see this page for more information on how to configure it: http://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/

Comment: You can test for this problem by temporarily disabling your firewall locally and seeing if you can now remote sync. If this fixes your problem, follow the first link above for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Use passive mode in your ftp settings

Answer (score 1):

People having this issue may have run into the Windows 7 with JDK 7 issue:

- http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201449
- http://forums.netbeans.org/topic36658-0-asc-0.html

The solution is to either downgrade your JDK or add some Windows Firewall exceptions for Java. Adding the exceptions didn't work for me, so downgrading the JDK to version 6 is my suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Run command prompt as admin and run

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you expand your answer to explain how to run a prompt as admin and what the command actually does?

Comment: Article [http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7077696] also suggest disableing stateful FTP inspection in the firewall, and it seems to help avoiding getting error

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this problem by allowing connections For NetBeans in Windows firewall, and created a new rule to allow connections for `Java/jdk.../bin/java.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you upgrade to Netbeans 6.9 you may have the same problem unless you check "Passive mode" in the settings.

Comment: It's working. I have just Checked the Passive Mode